# Autodiscover 2007 TLS not working

Tags: outlook, exchange-server

```
<Protocol>
    <Type>SMTP</Type>
    <Server>smtp.googlemail.com</Server>
    <LoginName><?=$user[0]['forward_email'];?></LoginName>
    <Port>587</Port>
    <DomainRequired>on</DomainRequired>
    <SPA>off</SPA>
    <Encryption>TLS</Encryption>
    <AuthRequired>on</AuthRequired>
    <UsePOPAuth>off</UsePOPAuth>
    <SMTPLast>off</SMTPLast>
</Protocol>
```

This on working with office outlook 2010/2013.
But office 2007 TLS change to SSL

Have try search over but nothing.
anything have fix this Please help

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this to work. I had exactly the same thing as you but removed the `SMTPLast` option. According to [this](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/2230e004-43e2-4531-8ac4-e54c580e446f/outlook-autodiscover-smtp-authentication?forum=outlook) it's only required when you don't have SMTP authentication but your server requires the user to login to pop/imap first.

Once i removed that, my autodiscover worked like a charm!

Here is the full xml output for reference:

```
<Autodiscover xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/responseschema/2006">
    <Response xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/autodiscover/outlook/responseschema/2006a">
        <User>
            <DisplayName>First Last</DisplayName>
        </User>
        <Account>
            <AccountType>email</AccountType>
            <Action>settings</Action>
            <Protocol>
                <Type>IMAP</Type>
                <Server>mail.example.com</Server>
                <Port>993</Port>
                <AuthRequired>on</AuthRequired>
                <LoginName>email@example.com</LoginName>
                <SPA>off</SPA>
                <SSL>on</SSL>
            </Protocol>
            <Protocol>
                <Type>SMTP</Type>
                <Server>mail.example.com</Server>
                <Port>587</Port>
                <AuthRequired>on</AuthRequired>
                <LoginName>email@example.com</LoginName>
                <SPA>off</SPA>
                <Encryption>TLS</Encryption>
                <UsePOPAuth>on</UsePOPAuth>
            </Protocol>
        </Account>
    </Response>
</Autodiscover>
```